# Pagination and Searching with FutureProvider (infinite_scroll_pagination+Riverpod)

Tags: flutter, pagination, flutter-dependencies, riverpod

**infinite_scroll_pagination with FutureProvider (Riverpod)**

usually i create a FutureProvider which is dependent on search query(StateProvider).

```
final allAgentSearchQueryProvider = StateProvider<String>((ref) {
  return '';
});

final allAgentProvider = FutureProvider<List<AgentPreviewModel>>(
  (ref) {
    final query = ref.watch(allAgentSearchQueryProvider);
    final type = ref.watch(agentTypeQueryProvider);
    return ref.watch(agentAPIProvider).getAllAgents(query, type);
  },
);
```

with this i can create easy AsyncValue with my search Query cause everytime i update StateProvider the futureProvider automatically update value.

I want this with infinite_scroll_pagination.

Comment: Thanks everyone. 
however i solve this problem with the help of chat GPT.


heres the code: [Gist Link] (https://gist.github.com/7ANV1R/ba49ffb6ae131943f48365876c5cf068)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is long enough to easily fit into this post. In a simple case, you can use the [riverpod_infinite_scroll](https://pub.dev/packages/riverpod_infinite_scroll) package, where pagination is already implemented.

Additional materials for self-implementation:

- [Infinite Pagination in Flutter with Firebase, Riverpod, and Freeze](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/infinite-pagination-in-flutter-with-riverpod/)
- [Seamless Infinite List with Riverpod in Flutter](https://itnext.io/seamless-infinite-list-with-riverpod-in-flutter-15369f3c9cd2)